# after creators update i have lost ability to take screenshots using winkey+prtscr keys.

Tags: windows-10

I was able to take screenshots using  winkey+prtscr keys prior to installing creators update 1703. I just realized today this is no longer working. Any help?

Comment: What do you believe that key combination should be doing?

Comment: Win+Print Screen - Take Screenshot of the virtual desktop and save it in `This PC\Pictures\Screenshots`

Comment: Well works fine on my prestine installation which means a third-party program is capturing the shortcut